# How to prevent removing connection ID (SignalR) in online chat?

Tags: javascript, signalr

Hi i used signl r to bulid onlline chat (users can send message to admin and admin can reply them),every thing is working fine but in user side pages if they go to other page connectionid  and user is getting removed,any solution how to do?
[This is the github project which i have used](https://github.com/upadhyayadhaval/SRChat)

Answer (score 0):

A new connection id is issued for each fresh connection (this includes when the page is unloaded, refreshed, changed etc). If you want to remember a user's information, just use a cookie or session variables and use an identifier in that.

Comment: hi can u explan me how to store values in session i tried cookie but some times i m getting undefined value,dont know where to keep session in tht

Comment: A basic overview of how to use the HttpContext.Session object to store variables can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I used cookie also but then also i am not getting,

Comment: Put a unique identifier (username, guid, whatever) in the cookie. Get the values from the cookie and use them in a `Register(uid)` sort of function from the client to enable the server to track the same user across multiple connections.

Comment: ^ Cookie or Session state.

Comment: i got solution for this add cookie in add user method if any body is using this chat application only

Answer (score -1):

In add user method add cookie like this (if you are using this chat application)

```
 HttpCookie ChatConnectioncookie = new HttpCookie("ChatConnection");
                ChatConnectioncookie.Values.Add("messageRecipientId", userId);
                ChatConnectioncookie.Values.Add("messageRecipientName", userName);
                ChatConnectioncookie.Values.Add("messageRecipientRole", userRole);
                ChatConnectioncookie.Values.Add("connectionId", Context.ConnectionId);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(ChatConnectioncookie);
                ChatConnectioncookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
```

ANd in connect method get cookie and manintain the connection..

Comment: So.. Exactly what I recommended then.